# Is MyTrip.com safe to use?

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I've found an itinerary on MyTrip.com that's well priced and can't seem to replicate the same fare on Google Flights. Is it safe to use?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/182639/how-do-i-get-a-refund-from-the-mytrip-travel-agency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like almost any online travel agency (OTA), they have poor reviews as people find them hard to deal with when things go wrong, and almost never review when things go right!

I run [Beat That Flight](https://beatthatflight.com.au/) which searches cheap flights, and one of the OTAs indexed is MyTrips.  I've booked with them before, and have had no problems.

However, one issue people can have is if their flight is cancelled - you need to get credit or whatever VIA the OTA, rather than the airline. And that can take time.  If you contact the airline, they'll tell you to contact the OTA, who then contacts the airline on your behalf.

So yes, they're legit. Yes, they're often much cheaper. But complications can occur.

Comment: Heavy warning: there's no amount of money that is worth risking your entire trip. Because that's what you do when going with companies like these. Unless you are a very experienced traveler who can easily deal with, as Mark said, complications, just book with airlines. Always. That 20, 30, even 200 dollars is just not worth it.

Comment: Booking directly with airlines is no guarantee you'll get good customer service and help in the event of problems. Read about Ryanair or some other budget airlines.

Comment: I booked a flight with their site, they wrote that buying check-in luggage is not possible but "you can always buy it in the airport before flight". It turned out that in the airport it cost 65 euros (while the ticket itself costs $75) and airline representative told me that I should've bought it on their site before the flight for something around $20. All in all, I will never use it again nor advise to anybody else.

Answer (score 11):

I was very skeptical given the [negative TripAdvisor reviews](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k9363013-Is_mytrip_com_legit_Has_anyone_used_them_lately-Air_Travel.html) but they support PayPal payments so I've figured I can always ask for a refund if it fails. Luckily it worked great - I've received all 3 confirmed PNRs within 30 seconds of completing the payment and all 3 PNRs worked correctly on the airline website. As far as I can tell MyTrip **is legit**.

**Update:** took the first two flights from the itinerary now, didn't encounter any issues. The third flight went fine too.

**Context**: I was searching for a multi-city itinerary from Central Asia to America to Europe and SkyScanner suggested booking it in one click on MyTrip. It seemed priced better than what I could find on Google Flights, though later I've realized it was due to splitting the itinerary into separate tickets vs. booking it as a single ticket. I could've purchased it all via airline websites (and probably would've, if I realized MyTrip's price is the same as 3 separate tickets), but in the end it worked and saved me extra clicks, so I have no complaints. Though I imagine a less-experienced traveler would be irked due to not realizing the difference between separate tickets vs. a single itinerary.

> NB: I'm not affiliated with MyTrip in any shape or form. Leaving this answer here as I couldn't find any credible reviews of their website and was nervous before booking.

Comment: Please come back after your trip and tell us how they handled problems, if any popped up.

Comment: I googled them (or rather 'Gotogate' as they mention that on their website) and it seems the difference might be in the booking conditions. You already mention that they booked you separate tickets rather than a multi-city. Perhaps it's worth comparing all the booking conditions on your booking with one of the more expensive options on SkyScanner to see if there are more notable differences?

Comment: @JJJ just checked and the only difference is that the single ticket on Emirates includes 23kg for both legs vs. 20kg if the Flydubai leg is separate. Otherwise same.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you have tickets. See my answer.

Comment: @chx yes, checked on Emirates, FlyDubai and Lufthansa websites right after booking. I’ve read the same bad reviews and only booked because I knew PayPal or my credit card will refund me if the tickets are fake. That being said I didn’t really save any money so they don’t add much value.

Comment: If that comforts you... and what happens to your trip if the tickets are fake? (Or, not fake right now but get cancelled down the line?)

Comment: @chx I get another ticket, then call Visa and get a chargeback. I'll find out for sure in 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4):

I used the MyTrip booking system and paid with my credit card. However, when the airline canceled my booking and I needed to reschedule my flight, I had a very hard time contacting them. First, I found the contact number on their website, as MyTrip directed me to do. I called the number, but the only response I received was: "We're sorry, please call again." I tried multiple times each day for over 10 days. I also sent an inquiry through their website. A few days later, I received an email providing another number to call. When I called that number, the phone company informed me that it had been disconnected. My only option was to continue sending emails. Finally, after more than 30 days, I received a call from India. Unfortunately, the phone connection was poor and the call dropped multiple times. Eventually, the call dropped again and they never called me back. Now, after over 40 days, my airline ticket has still not been rescheduled! My only saving grace is that my booked date is for March 19th, so I still have 45 days to try to reschedule the ticket. I hope to resolve my issue, provided that MyTrip assists me.

Comment: I’d ask your bank for a chargeback in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

They are the worst I have ever encountered. They tried to extort 2 payments for a flexible ticket change of departure date. Then they changed my ticket from refundable to non-refundable, without my knowledge or consent and when I cancelled my flight it took them a month to get back to me. By then I had travelled with someone else and I now find that they are refusing to refund, even though they made the changes and I didn't know - absolutely criminal

Answer (score 2):

For some odd reason changing the flight has to be done over the phone. Instead of acting on the email "please change my flight from this date to that date for all passengers, yes, thank you" they:

- ask you to call,
- wait 40 minutes in the que,
- ask you to spell the order number, repeating it 4 times
- then having you wait for 20 minutes until they effectively are looking for their colleague to make the change

Mytrip.com tickets are not cheaper than buying directly from the flight companies and they have ultimately high friction upon any kind of changes.

Answer (score 1):

My trip.com are an absolute nightmare to deal with if anything goes wrong with your trip, or you have flight cancellations etc..
If all you want is the absolute lowest price possible to get somewhere, then crack on and use them, but I would advise you to get the most comprehensive travel insurance available.

I think they have the worst customer support phone service I've ever encountered. If you don't believe me just try ringing the support number before you book a flight, if someone speaks to you within an hour you are extremely lucky, now imagine that you are stuck in an airport or a foreign country with a cancelled flight and you're trying to get hold of them!!
There isn't even any route you can take on their website to complain or highlight this inept service.
It's just not worth whatever the saving on the flight is, they really are a terribly run company.