# Is it possible to get a refund or reschedule a flight booked with MyTrip.com?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, refunds

I believe this company is entirely deceptive, run by individuals in India who don't have a firm grasp of English, making it nearly impossible to comprehend the individuals who answer their calls.

I purchased two tickets and spent over $113 on the flexible ticket option. Unfortunately, I had a severe accident the day prior (which I can provide evidence for) and called 24 hours in advance to attempt to reschedule or cancel my flight and receive a refund. I made several calls and always ended up speaking to people who were incredibly difficult to understand. I requested escalation to a manager, but I was informed that none were available, a response I received across multiple calls and different individuals. I even reached out to them via email. Their unanimous response was that there was nothing they could do and that I needed to call the airline directly. When I did so, the airline refuted the claims made by this company, but since my ticket was purchased through them, there was nothing the airline could do to reschedule the flight either. However, the airline did inform me that if I cancelled the flight, I would at least get a refund on the airport fees, which amounts to about 10% of the ticket price.

As of today, I've not received any refund, nor have I been able to reschedule the flight. I lost all the money I spent on this. Does anyone have any advice on how I can secure at least a partial refund? I am confident that if there hadn't been any issues, everything would have been fine, but considering that their prices were only around $20 cheaper than other more reputable companies, I will never take such a risk again and do business with them.

I appreciate any feedback you can provide!

Comment: Related (not duplicate):  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168582/4171

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it feels more like a rant/negative review disguised as a question, than an actual answerable question.

Comment: This is really just a rant about a particular supplier of services. You should speak to them or a consumer group in your country to see what is possible.

Answer (score 3):

> Did anybody have any advice on how to get at least a partial refund?

Squeaky wheel gets the grease. I think your only chance is to keep calling and threaten to initiate a charge back on your credit card. Eventually you may find an agent who will actually process your refund. Whether that's worth the significant investment in time, effort and aggravation is yours to decide.

> paid over $113 for the flexible ticket optioe

Flex tickets are rarely worth it. Typically the only difference to a regular ticket is that they waive the change fee, but paying $100 more to save a $50 change fee really makes no sense. You also need to carefully read the terms and conditions of what "flex" actually means for your specific ticket.

> I had a terrible accident the day before

I'm sorry that this happened to you and I hope you have recovered. However this type of risk typically covered through travel insurance, not through the airline or booking agent. In this case both have the right to treat this as "not our problem".

> I will never take a risk and deal with them again

Lesson learned. Unless you have a really strong reason it's always the best option to book directly with the airline. If anything goes wrong the airlines says "the booking agent needs to handle this" and the booking agent says "the airline needs to handle this". This is typically spelled out in the terms and conditions of both which you did agree when you booked it. This means that you agreed to basically have no customer service and no accountability.

Comment: I agree with and have upvoted your answer. It would be clearer, however, if the second sentence began "If you book with a booking agent or online travel agency, then if anything goes wrong..."