# How do I get a refund from the Mytrip travel agency?

Tags: air-travel, refunds

Exactly two months ago, my daughter and her two friends booked flights through Mytrip. Unfortunately, their flight was cancelled. The airline has already refunded Mytrip for all three passengers' bookings, yet my daughter and her friends haven't received any of their money back.

We have spoken to 19 representatives from Mytrip so far, all of whom say the same thing: 'Your refund request has been prioritized' or 'We have escalated your refund request to the support team/refund team/back office'. They promise that their supervisor will call back, but we never hear from anyone. It's also frustrating that you can't reply to an email sent by Mytrip; instead, you have to keep sending new emails for correspondence.

According to their website, our refund claim, which has already been approved by the airline, is still 'waiting to process payout.' The website also claims their 'phone support offers fast assistance' and their 'support team can swiftly handle requests.' However, this has proven to be false. How long does Mytrip need to process a refund to the passenger? They claimed it would take six days back at the end of June! Another month has passed, and we have yet to see a refund.

In total, it's been two months since the flight was cancelled, and we haven't received any refunds. Is Mytrip intentionally holding onto the money to gain interest? I wonder how those responsible for these unprofessional and unethical practices at Mytrip can sleep at night.

I am willing to withdraw this review if Mytrip rectifies the situation and refunds my daughter and her friends ASAP. They worked hard to save for this special trip to Europe. If this matter isn't resolved immediately, our next steps will be to contact television stations for an investigative story on Mytrip and to file a legal complaint. How can they get their refund?

Comment: myTrip has 1 out of 5 stars here https://www.sitejabber.com/reviews/mytrip.com I doubt that you'll see any money back.

Comment: I would check out with your bank if a chargeback is legally possible

Comment: What country are they in? How did they pay and when? Was it a single transaction or several? What’s the amount?

Comment: 0 out of 4 stars would probably be more accurate

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt on sites like https://www.productreview.com.au/listings/mytrip-comor or https://www.hellopeter.com/mytrip-com one star is the minimum.

Comment: @DimitriVulis yes, misleading scale.